# "The violence on TV shows are bad for childrens" or "The violence on TV shows is bad for childrens"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

I'm confused with these two. Which of them is grammatically correct?

- "The violence on TV shows **are** bad for childrens"
- "The violence on TV shows **is** bad for childrens"

My teacher said that I am wrong for answering "The violence on TV shows is bad for childrens." I answered this because I thought the bad thing was the violence, not the TV shows.

Comment: Hello @Randipa. Welcome to ELL. Please look at the question thoroughly after my suggested edit is approved (if it is approved). You will see the changes I made (or if someone else makes it) in the revision part. You can get get it by clicking on the __edited at [time_format]__. This will appear only when the edit is done. So until then wait. And do not forget to see it.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer

> The violence on TV shows is bad for childrens.

is almost correct but note that *children* is already plural so the *s* is not needed

> The violence on TV shows is bad for children.

is the way to go. As you state the subject is *violence* which is singular.

Comment: Unless they're speaking African-American Vernacular English, which sometimes uses "chilluns" to mean "children".

Comment: @nick012000: Have you any evidence for that? To the extent that AAVE is a "true dialect" (as opposed to "pidgin", or just "uneducated"), I'd say the singular/plural nouns are ***chile*** and ***chillun***. I suspect the "hypercorrected" version ***chilluns*** might be more likely to appear in fictional narrative contexts written by a non-AAVE author who *doesn't* actually know the dialect very well.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica It's listed on Urban Dictionary, at least. https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=chillens